# Manga about two girls summoned to another world; one has charm powers, while the other has a connection to spirits and took the form of a cat

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga some time ago, and I want to see if there are new chapters. So from what I can remember, two girls got summoned to another world; one had the power to somehow charm people around her, and the other, from what I remember, had some connection with spirits. The one who had a connection with spirits ran away to another country, where she took on the form of a cat and is the guest of the king.

The king is also looking for her in human form. And she is treated like a special being, if I remember correctly, so they don't anger the spirits. The king of the country that she ran to, I think, was some kind of dragon kin, and at some point the other country declares war on them for some reason just to lose very fast.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And can you tell us the hair colour/s of the two girls?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the manga **The White Cat's Revenge as Plotted from the Dragon King's Lap**

Here is the summary from the [publishers page](https://yenpress.com/titles/9781975317485-the-white-cat-s-revenge-as-plotted-from-the-dragon-king-s-lap-vol-1):

> Ruri just can’t get away from Asahi! Her clingy, oblivious childhood
> friend is beloved by absolutely everyone, making Ruri the target of
> resentment and jealousy from Asahi’s horde of groupies. When Asahi is
> summoned to another world to be their “Priestess Princess,” of course
> Ruri gets dragged along for the ride—and branded a traitor who must be
> exiled to the woods! But now that Ruri is finally out of Asahi’s
> shadow, she may just find that a new world is the perfect place for a
> new beginning...

Here is the reason why it fits:

- MC is beloved by the spirits of the world
- MC's childhood friend unconsciously charms the people around her, but MC is unaffected by it
- Because of the charm, the country the girls were summoned, decided to kick out the MC for being useless and potentially harmful to childhood friend
- MC get's a bracelet which allows her to transform into a cat
- MC wanders into the dragon nation, where she's found to be a "beloved", **but** this happens while she's still transformed as a cat
- The dragon king saw the MC once in her human body and felt a special affection for her (basically love at first sight). But then he meets her in her cat form without realizing that the human and cat are one and the same person (MC also doesn't realize that she met the dragon king while she was in human form)
- A war happens between the human nation and dragon nation because the childhood friend thought the dragon nation kidnapped the MC (the human king hid the fact that they kicked the MC out).

Here is a scene in Ch. 2 where MC finds out she's beloved by the spirits because of her magical wavelength:
[image]

In Ch. 5 MC transforms into a cat for the first time:
[image]

In Ch. 10 we see that the dragon king's retainer are looking for the woman the dragon king might be interessted in. Note that the (and the MC) doesn't realize that they are talking about the MC.
[image]